# How to propagate progress from root MotionLayout to its child RecyclerView which contains MotionLayout item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I have fragment with `MotionLayout` (1). One of the child layouts is expanded by swiping it down (custom-made Toolbar). This child layout contains `RecyclerView` with another `MotionLayout` (2) inside each item.

`TransitionListener` is connected to (1).

When `MotionLayout` (1) detects swiping transition (with `TransitionListener`) it should propagate its `progress` to currently visible `RecyclerView` item's MotionLayout (2) so that animation of the custom-made Toolbar expanding AND animation of the visible `RecyclerView` item are synchronized.

Problem is that although `RecyclerView` item receives `progress` value manually sent by `TransitionListener.onTransitionChange` method, `RecyclerView` item animation is frozen to one of the start/end states and no animation is visible.

Outside `RecyclerView` custom-made Toolbar swiping down sends progress to `MotionLayout` (2) and state changing and animations occur normally.

`MotionScene` is programmatically added to each `RecyclerView` item's `MotionLayout` because data is dynamic and cannot be described in `motion_scene.xml`  of the MotionLayout (2) alone. (I used the https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/working-with-dynamic-data-in-motionlayout-9dbbcfe5ff75 method for programmatically adding MotionScene transitions and states).

How do I have `MotionLayout` (1) which propagates progress to `RecyclerView` item's 'MotionLayout' (2)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't a way to do this with `RecyclerView` without some Kotlin. Below I'll go into detail about how to do that.

---

The way I've propagated progress to each `ViewHolder` is to set a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and within `onScrolled`:

- Get a reference to the `RecyclerView`'s current `LayoutManager`
- Use `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition` to get the range of `ViewHolder`s I should be looking for.
- Use `LayoutManager.findViewByPosition` to get a `View` reference and `RecyclerView.getChildViewHolder` to get each `ViewHolder` reference.
- Filter out null results
- Calculate the progress for each particular `ViewHolder` for my use-case.
- Update the progress of each `ViewHolder`

In practice (and with some extension functions that handle those bits) the overall flow in Kotlin should look like this:

```kotlin
recyclerView.activeViewHolders(onlyVisible = true)
    .mapNotNull { viewHolder -> viewHolder as? WidgetViewHolder }
    .forEach { viewHolder ->
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        val awayFromCenter = recyclerView.calculateHorizontalOffsetPercentage(position)
        viewHolder.resize(awayFromCenter)
    }
```

This solution has worked smoothly for me with both Kotlin synthetics & ViewBinding.

---

Because you mentioned you have pretty dynamic data it doesn't sound like `Carousel` can work for you, but you should check it out as its currently in development: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Carousel